# How to create a module[qpython3]

Tags: qpython3

Noob alert!

I'm wondering how you go about importing a module(one made in qpython)?
I've tried making a new folder and adding a setup.py then trying to import but just get error about module not found(or something)..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your folder must to consist in Path variable. 
You must append path to your folder in this variable.
Add the following lines to the top of your project main file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(yourPath)
```

yourPath must be a string type. For example:

'/storage/sdcard0/myfolder'